# How do I remove duplicate objects in a List based on Object's single property match?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, removeall

I have two lists new Java:

```
public class SomeDto() {
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  public Long qty;
}

List<SomeDto> someDtoList1 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();
List<SomeDto> someDtoList2 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();
```

I want to do something like this:

```
someDtoList1.removeAll(someDtoList2);
```

But only based on the id property. Can this be done in a single call somehow in java 7? Or do I need to write my own logic?

Comment: If id is a key, why not use Map<Long, SomeDto> instead of List<SomeDto>?

Comment: Add Map instead of List.

Answer (score 2):

Steps in a nut-shell:

- First create getters inside your class.
- Add a default constructor so that you can create new objects and add them to the list.
- Then add a few objects to your list.
- Iterate over that list. Search for your desired property using the getter.
- If matches, add to another list.
- Use remove all method

  ```
      public static class SomeDto {

          public Long id;
          public String name;
          public Long qty;

          public SomeDto(Long id, String name, Long qty) {
              this.qty = qty;
              this.name = name;
              this.id = id;
          }

          public Long getId() {
              return id;
          }

          public String getName() {
              return name;
          }

          public Long getQty() {
              return qty;
          }
      }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

      List<SomeDto> someDtoList1 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();
      List<SomeDto> someDtoList2 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();

      someDtoList1.add(new SomeDto((long) 1, "Scarlett Johannson", (long) 100));
      someDtoList1.add(new SomeDto((long) 2, "Emma Stone", (long) 101));
      someDtoList1.add(new SomeDto((long) 3, "Ariana Grande", (long) 1));

     for(SomeDto it: someDtoList1){// Just displaying the newly created list

      System.out.println("Id: " + it.getId() + " Name: " + it.getName() + " QTY: " + it.getQty());
  }

      for(SomeDto it: someDtoList1){// Iterating over the list

          if (it.getId() == (long) 3) {// Searching for criteria
              someDtoList2.add(it);// when a match is found add to another list
          }
       }

  someDtoList1.removeAll(someDtoList2);// removing the objects

  System.out.println("After removal of 3rd ID: ");

     for(SomeDto it: someDtoList1){// Displaying the final list

       System.out.println("Id: " + it.getId() + " Name: " + it.getName() + " QTY: " + it.getQty());
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: I think he mentioned Java 7, so lambdas won't work.

Comment: @Gondy No problem, using a simple iterator is a work-around. I have updated. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement `equals` method on `SomeDto.id` property. Then iterate over `someDtoList1` and call method `someDtoList2.contains(curretDto)`. If it returns true you can remove `currentDto` from `someDtoList1`. You can use `java.util.Iterator` for this.

```
class SomeDto {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public Long qty;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return id == obj.id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<SomeDto> someDtoList1 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();
        List<SomeDto> someDtoList2 = new ArrayList<SomeDto>();

        for (Iterator iterator = someDtoList1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            SomeDto someDto = (SomeDto) iterator.next();
            if (someDtoList2.contains(someDto)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can only override `equals` method in `SomeDto` class to compare only `id` property.

But in general it is very dangerous: 
  Anywhere in the code two `SomeDto` objects will be considered equal if their ids are equal.

If you are sure it is acceptable you can do it like:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof SomeDto)) return false;
        SomeDto otherDto = (SomeDto)other;
        return (null == this.id?otherDto.id == null: this.id.equals(otherDto.id);           
    }
```

PS. in most cases it is not acceptable, specifically with DTO.